# Herencia de una instancia de servicios web C#

Tags: c#, webservice, herencia

Buenos dias, yo se que el titulo es un poco confuso pero voy a tratar de explicar mi problema.

Estoy trabajando en un software que consume varios servicios web, para hacer una serie de operaciones CRUD, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es optimizar un poco el programa, para que cada vez que abra un formulario no instancie los servicios web que usa dicho formulario.

Para ello cree una clase clsincio que insatancia todos los servicios web que usa todo el software en el momento del login, de esta manera.

```
public class ClsInicio
{
    public SerEnajenacionBienesService SerEnajenacion;
    public ServiciosGeneralesCompService SerGeneralesComp;
    public ServiciosAccesoriasCompService SerAccesoriasComp;
    public ServiciosDocumentosService SerDocumentos;
    public Funciones SerFunciones;
}
public void MtdCargar()
{
    SerEnajenacion = WS.SerEnajenacionBienesService(); return;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

ahora el problema es que no se como acceder a la instancia que hice en esta clase

ya que si de un formulario hago los siguiente

```
clsinicio inicio = new clsinicio();

inicio.SerEnajenacion...... etc
```

obtengo un error ya que el servicio queda establecido en null, supongo que por hacer new sobre la clase.

yo creo que se puede hacer con algo de herencia, pero no tengo muy claro como seria, ya que en la mayoria de las veces tengo que hacer herencia desde la clase clsinicio a formularios form.

Espero quede un poco claro, y me puedan dar una luz

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que noto es que no instancias los servicios

```
public class ClsInicio
{
    public readonly SerEnajenacionBienesService SerEnajenacion;
    public readonly ServiciosGeneralesCompService SerGeneralesComp;
    public readonly ServiciosAccesoriasCompService SerAccesoriasComp;
    public readonly ServiciosDocumentosService SerDocumentos;
    public readonly Funciones SerFunciones;

    public ClsInicio()
    {
        SerEnajenacion = new SerEnajenacionBienesService();
        SerGeneralesComp = new ServiciosGeneralesCompService();
        //resto de los servicios
    }

    //resto codigo

}
```

como observaras en el constructor de la clase creas las instancias de los servicios

se define como `readonly` para que solo se pueda instanciar desde el constructor

Comment: En la parte de abajo instancio el servicio. tengo un metodo que hace los siguiente SerEnajenacion = WS.SerEnajenacionBienesService(); return; esa es la instancia

Comment: pero no lo estas invocando si solo realizas el new de la clase cuando la utilizas, es por eso que se recomienda hacer esto en el constructor de la clase

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya comprendi a que te referias, funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Una forma en que puedes obtener el resultado que buscas es con una clase Lazy. Esta clase delata la instanciacion de la clase hasta el momento en el que es requrida.

Podrias hacer algo asi:

```
public class ClsInicio
{
    readonly Lazy<SerEnajenacionBienesService> _serEnajenacion;
    public SerEnajenacionBienesService SerEnajenacion {
        get {
            return _serEnajenacion.Value;
        }
    }
    readonly Lazy<ServiciosGeneralesCompService> _serGeneralesComp;
    public ServiciosGeneralesCompService SerGeneralesComp {
        get {
            return _serGeneralesComp.Value;
        }
    }
    readonly Lazy<ServiciosAccesoriasCompService> _serAccesoriasComp;
    public ServiciosAccesoriasCompService SerAccesoriasComp {
        get {
            return _serAccesoriasComp.Value;
        }
    }
    readonly Lazy<ServiciosDocumentosService> _serDocumentos;
    public ServiciosDocumentosService SerDocumentos {
        get {
            return _serDocumentos.Value;
        }
    }
    readonly Lazy<Funciones> _serFunciones;
    public Funciones SerFunciones {
        get {
            return _serFunciones.Value;
        }
    }
    public ClsInicio()
    {
        _serEnajenacion = new Lazy<SerEnajenacionBienesService> (() => WS.SerEnajenacionBienesService());
        _serGeneralesComp = new Lazy<ServiciosGeneralesCompService> (() => WS.ServiciosGeneralesCompService());
        _serAccesoriasComp = new Lazy<ServiciosAccesoriasCompService> (() => WS.ServiciosAccesoriasCompService());
        _serDocumentos = new Lazy<ServiciosDocumentosService> (() => WS.ServiciosDocumentosService());
        _serFunciones = new Lazy<Funciones> (() => WS.Funciones());
    }

}
```

1. Creas un campo readonly de tipo Lazy que hara la magia del lazy loading.
2. Creas una propiedad del mismo tipo de tu Servico, esta es la que usaras para acceder al servicio, puedes ver que se manda llamar a la propiedad .Value, esto es lo que dispara la instanciacion de la clase hasta el momento en el que el servicio es usado.
3. En el constructor instancias los Lazy loader y de parametro le envias un delegado con el que instanciarias el servicio que necesita.

De esta forma los servicios seran instanciados hasta que los necesites aligerando el uso de tu clase en las formas.

**Nota:** Es probable que este codigo necesite modificaciones ya que no conozco la forma en que instancias los servicios.

Aqui puedes encontrar la [documentacion de la clase Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)